# Rails 4 integration tests: Routes back to same page

Tags: testing, integration-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

In my routes, I have the following:

```
match '/:org_id/users/:id/receive_message' => 'users#receive_message', :via => [:get, :post], :org_id => /[a-z0-9.-]+/i, :id => /[a-z0-9.-]+/i
```

In my route tests I have the following:

```
assert_routing({method: 'post', path: '/test4.example.com/users/user.test.email/receive_message'}, {controller: "users", action: "receive_message", org_id: "test4.example.com", id: "user.test.email"})
```

Which works fine. Except when I do an integration test on the action with

```
post "/123/users/456/receive_message"
```

I get a 301 redirect to http://example.com/123/users/456/receive_message

I have turned off devise authentication and authenticity_token checking for this action. It never gets to any of the before_* filters in the integration test. The action is working fine in production. Using stock Rails 4 test framework for units, controllers, and integration tests, and FactoryGirl for mocks.

Any ideas?